# Difference Between Adaline and Delta Rules

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

What's The difference between the Adaline and Delta rules in Neural Networks ?

Answer (score -1):

None: ADALINE is an acronym for ADAptive LINear Element; [The ADALINE learning rule, also known as the the delta rule, is a training rule that minimises the output error using (approximate) gradient descent.](http://lcn.epfl.ch/tutorial/english/apb/html/theory.html)